# Excel COUNTIFS with wildcard on numeric data

Tags: excel, countif

Can Excel COUNTIFS function use a wildcard to match numeric data?  E.g. with the following contrived table:

[image]

I want to have a dropdown menu using Data Validation that allows the user to select 1, 2, 3, or * (wildcard).  Then Excel should count the number of Ringtailed lemurs that equal the selected Age, where * will result in counting all the Ringtailed lemurs.

If the user selects 1, the output will be 2.  If the user selects 2, the output will be 1.  If the user selects 3, the output will be 0.  And if the user selects *, the output will be 3.

This formula counts the number of Ringtailed lemurs when Age is 1

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,1,B2:B7,"Ringtailed")
```

But this formula does not count the total number of Ringtailed lemurs:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"*",B2:B7,"Ringtailed")
```

My problem is that COUNTIFS doesn't seem to allow wildcard to match any numeric value, but only any text value.  If I enter the Ages as '1, '2, '3, '1, '2, '3, then the above formula works.  But I can't reformat the Age reference.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"<>",B2:B7,"Ringtailed")` maybe

Comment: (though really, should just be `=COUNTIFS(B2:B7,"Ringtailed")`.

Comment: That works!  I had to omit the double quotes when I put it into my cell range for Data Validation from List, but it works like I wanted the asterisk to.  I.e. my Data Validation range for the dropdown selection is 1, 2, 3, <>.  Not 1, 2, 3, "<>".

Comment: `<>` is really just the equivalent of "non-blank" btw.

Comment: I can't omit the Age criteria entirely since the Age will be coming from a drop-down selection box

Comment: So select the number 1, 2 etc and >0

Comment: Be careful as `"<>"` will return positive if the cell has a formula that returns and empty string `""`  But if the data is entered manually then this is probably the best approach.

Comment: I like >0 also.  Thanks!

Comment: You could also use something like `All` in the drop down and use an IF to decide what to do: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,IF(D2="All","<>",D2),B2:B7,"Ringtailed")` where D2 is your drop down.  Just a note.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I like that idea too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So went with my comment as so:

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,D2,B2:B7,D4)
```

Cells D2 and D4 have data validation drop downs that allow selection of items in the lists.

Using countifs gives a different result:

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,D2,B2:B7,D4)
```

And adding * to the list of types will count all of them.
Note the rows should be down to 7 not like the image that shows 6.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike!